# Not able to convert html code to pdf

Tags: html, ios, swift

I have an html template. I want to convert it into a pdf and share.

When I do something like so...

```
let activityViewController:UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems:  [self.appDelegate.HTMLContent], applicationActivities: nil)

self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Then what is shared is just the html code. I wanted to convert the html code to pdf and then share it. What am I to do for it...?

Answer (score 1):

Use following method to convert your HTML string to PDF data format of A4 size:

```
func generatePDF(from html: String) -> NSData {

    let fmt = UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter(markupText: html)

    // 2. Assign print formatter to UIPrintPageRenderer
    let render = UIPrintPageRenderer()
    render.addPrintFormatter(fmt, startingAtPageAt: 0)

    // 3. Assign paperRect and printableRect
    let page = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 595.2, height: 841.8) // A4, 72 dpi
    let printableRect = CGRect(x: 47.6, y: 70.9, width: 500, height: 700) // Adding margin to page
    render.setValue(page, forKey: "paperRect")
    render.setValue(printableRect, forKey: "printableRect")

    // 4. Create PDF context and draw
    let pdfData = NSMutableData()
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, .zero, nil)

    for i in 0..<render.numberOfPages {
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage()
        render.drawPage(at: i, in: UIGraphicsGetPDFContextBounds())
    }

    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()

    return pdfData
}
```

Now use the following code to share it:

```
let pdfData = generatePDF(from: self.appDelegate.HTMLContent)
let activityViewController:UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [pdfData], applicationActivities: nil)

self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Pass this data in place of `self.appDelegate.HTMLContent` in `UIActivityViewController`

Comment: well..I'm a bit confused. In the button click action where I want the `activityViewController` to come up, I first called the above method like so...`generatePDF(from: self.appDelegate.HTMLContent)`. Now how do I proceed...?

Comment: .@Mukesh I already tried the exact same thing you suggested. But when I go ahead and select a recipient for the pdf I get the message `This item cannot be shared. Please select a different item`

Comment: I can use the same code to share the HTML content. Just verify your code. I just tested it with Message and Mail app.

Comment: I want to share it with whatsapp..Could it be the issue..?

Comment: also printing `pdfData` gives me this...`<25504446 2d312e33 0a25c4e5 f2e5eba7 f3a0d0c4 c60a3420 30206f62 6a0a3c3c 202f4c65 6e677468 20352030 2052202f 46696c74 657....` Hope this is right..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171138/discussion-between-mukesh-and-v-bw).